# lumen oauth 2 generate new access token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth, oauth-2.0

I need to get the OAuth 2.0 new access token in lumen.

**My Routes**

```
Route::get('callback', function () {
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->get('http://localhost/Yuvaraj/lumen/public/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'client_secret',
            'client_id' => 2,
            'client_secret' => 'hDT0Sym8rfxtgt577QBvgkOtDZd7SLfoik93nkmk',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/Yuvaraj/lumen/public/callback',
            'scope' => ''
        ],
    ]);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($response);echo "</pre>";
    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
});

Route::get('token', function(){
    return 'Hello world';
});
```

i can't get new access token

Thanks again...

Comment: What exactly the error you are getting?

Comment: Empty response coming. I didn't see my access token.
I need to generate a custom access token in my lumen application.